# Image on xml in Android Studio stretches abnormally height wise

Tags: android, json

Edit: The problem with my image is of resolution so higher the resolution the more blank space there is. But I can't get the right resolution. If the resolution is too high the problem is right here and if it is enough to fit the image to a 720p display then the image quality is so bad on QHD or higher displays. I can't seem to find any other solution on the internet other than the resolution thing so please help!

The image I put on XML has no visible layout_marginVertical. I did not put that attribute there and if I do write that it does put that margin vertically resulting in a confused situation. This happens even though I wrapped all the content. This is the image I inserted in my code:

[image]

And this is the result I get:

[image: ![result]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
    tools:context=".RegistrationActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/android_course_thumbnail"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundcolor"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: your image resolution might be too high

Comment: @VivekMishra the image is 1920 x 1080

Comment: reduce the resolution

Comment: What is the ideal kind of resolution?

Comment: I don't know about the ideal but this issue is due to the high resolution image

Comment: use 9 patch image generator

Answer (score 0):

Remove scrollview, and resize image to 480x800 resolution

Comment: But I need the scroll view because I'll add 7-8 cards later.

Comment: Then replace wrap_content with match parent

Answer (score 0):

### Try It

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>


                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>


                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/listrow"
        app:menu="@menu/main" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use scaletype="fitxy" in xml of imageview